# infinite loop on Dart

Tags: dart, infinite-loop

Is there still a bug in this code that can cause an infinite loop? Please explain if there is, Thank you

```
String username;
bool notValid = false;

do {
stdout.write('Masukkan nama Anda (min. 6 karakter): ');
username = stdin.readLineSync();

if (username.length < 6 ) {
notValid = true;
print('Username Anda tidak valid');
}
} while (notValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to set the `notValid` to `false` after the correct attempt.

example:

```dart
if (username.length < 6 ) {
  notValid = true;
  print('Username Anda tidak valid');
} else {
  notValid = false;
}
```

Anyway, here is the full code with null safety.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  String? username;
  bool notValid = false;

  do {
    print(notValid);
    stdout.write('Masukkan nama Anda (min. 6 karakter): ');
    username = stdin.readLineSync();

    if (username != null && username.length < 6) {
      notValid = true;
      print('Username Anda tidak valid');
    } else {
      notValid = false;
    }
  } while (notValid);
}
```